# react native webview doesn't work on Android - ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I have a react-native app and I am trying to open a webview with a token in query params.
[It works fine on iOS, but on Android I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDkIr.jpg)
I cannot see any other error in the debugger.

My first thought was that the url is too long, because it has approximately 3500 characters, but if I copy the url and paste it in Chrome it opens the page.
I also searched the limits for browsers and it should work even if the url is very long.

Do you have any idea what should be the problem here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your data come from api or php database?

Comment: have you resolved this? I am getting the same error